# Can we create an anonymous inner class from a concrete class?

Tags: java, abstract-class, anonymous-class

There is something surprising in the following code. The `ListCell` class is not abstract, but we were able to create an anonymous class from it and override its method! How is this possible?

```
ListCell<TodoItem> listCell = new ListCell<>() {
    @Override
    public void updateIndex(int i) {
        super.updateIndex(i);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why would it **not** be possible?  You can subclass any class that is not declared **final**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of anonymous classes (cf. [JLS, §15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)) is simply not related/restricted to abstract classes.

`new ListCell<>() {}` creates an instance of a subclass (with a synthetic name) of `ListCell`. Subclassing is possible unless the parent class is final. Subclasses can override methods from the parent class unless they're final.